# MS Access Openform - Blank Field Values Desired

Tags: ms-access, openform

I have a form that I want to open to view data on a table.

I have a search box in the header where I can search for a customer record I want by entering their ID.  It works.

However, when I open the form initially the first record in the data table populates.  I want to avoid this until I enter the value in the search box and execute the code.

I've been scouring google and can't figure out how to do this.

Help appreciated.

Comment: That depends heavily on how your current search works. Please add the code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Options:

1. Set the Filter property in form design with criteria that will not return records, set FilterOnLoad to Yes
2. Don't have RecordSource set in design, set it with code after filter criteria is selected
3. Use dynamic parameterized query that references combobox as parameter